# Infinite loop error EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Firstly look my code :

These are in my activity;

```
EditText text1,text2; (Are defined corretly not problem)
text1.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(onePercent));
text2.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(twoPercent));
..                                   ..
..                                   ..
..                                   ..
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view; 

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view; 

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)         {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) 
    {}


    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        String text = editable.toString();
        switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.dis_one_percent: (this is text1)
            if(!text.equel(""))             
               text2.setText(Double.toString(text));            

            break;
        case R.id.dis_one_number: (and text2)
            if(!text.equel(""))            
            text1.setText(Double.toString(text+"LOL"));                  


    }



    }
}
```

Goal: when the user enters the some value in the text1 area, I want to trigger text2 area.  But when user enters a value to text1 area, text2's MyTextWatcher was triggered. There is an infinite loop. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Just curious... isn't `text.equel("")` giving you a compiling error?

Comment: i am not copy/paste the my code. Just write again. (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i solved my problem. Thats really simple. (:

just check the isFocused() before the  setText();

```
case R.id.dis_one_percent: (this is text1)
        if(!text.equals("")) 
        {            
          if( text1.isFocused())
             text2.setText(Double.toString(text));      
        }      

        break;
    case R.id.dis_one_number: (and text2)
        if(!text.equals(""))   
        {    
            if( text2.isFocused())     
               text1.setText(Double.toString(text+"LOL")); 
        }
```

Sorry for your time. And thanks for your replies...

Comment: +1. Awesome, just saved my day! As simple as it may look, I was struggling with this as I was setting/unsettings tags between the text fields and it was becoming very complex, plus it didn't really quite work..

Comment: You can also add/remove the change listener on focus change, that's what I did, but your solution pointed me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove text change listener when you change text.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
     text1.removeTextChangedListener(onePercent);
     text2.removeTextChangedListener(twoPercent);
    String text = editable.toString();
    switch(view.getId()){

    case R.id.dis_one_percent: (this is text1)
        if(!text.equel(""))             
           text2.setText(Double.toString(text));            

        break;
    case R.id.dis_one_number: (and text2)
        if(!text.equel(""))            
        text1.setText(Double.toString(text+"LOL"));                  
   }
   text1.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(onePercent));
   text2.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(twoPercent));

}
```

Comment: You have to remove both text1 and text2 and then add again. The two edits text you post later so  I thought you have only one edit text.

Comment: This idea works completely. Even it is better than accepted answer because does not depend on `focus`.